# Add alternative text for an image in Tagged PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, pdfa

I need your help with this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary catalog = reader.getCatalog();
    PdfDictionary structTreeRoot =
        catalog.getAsDict(PdfName.STRUCTTREEROOT);
    manipulate(structTreeRoot);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(
        reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
}

public void manipulate(PdfDictionary element) {
    if (element == null)
        return;
    if (PdfName.FIGURE.equals(element.get(PdfName.S))) {
        element.put(PdfName.ALT,
            new PdfString("Figure without an Alt description"));
    }
    PdfArray kids = element.getAsArray(PdfName.K);
    if (kids == null) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < kids.size(); i++)
        manipulate(kids.getAsDict(i));
}
```

I can port this Java example to C#:

Get the root dictionary from the PdfReader object,
Get the root of the structure tree (a dictionary),
Loop over all the kids of every branch of that tree,
When a lead is a figure, add an /Alt entry.
Once this is done, use PdfStamper to save the altered file.

But how could I do it?

Could you help me please?

Thank's!

Comment: What exactly keeps you from simply *porting this Java example to C#*?

Comment: Hey hello, thank you for having responded to me. I do not know what methods / classes to use to do porting from java to c#!

Comment: The main problem is not iText or iTextSharp. The main problem is your refusal to understand your assignment. You are trying to cheat your customer. Please be aware of that. In some countries, there are high penalties for cheating with accessible PDF.

Comment: Lol Bruno, thx this is a private test for generating pdf/a and signing it for university project!! :) I'm not cheating nobody!  Anyway thank's!