# Alternate description needed for Figure when creating a PDF/A Level A document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, pdfa

I'm trying to generate a PDF/A 1A, 2A or 3A  with iText for C#, but I encounter this problem:

> "Alt entry should specify alternate description for /Figure element."

My code looks like this:

```
public byte[] GeneratePDFA(byte[] inputPdf)
{
    //System.out.println("PDF to PDF/A");
    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    PdfReader reader = null;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        // step 2:
        // we create a writer that listens to the document
        // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
        PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.GetInstance(document, ms, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);
        writer.SetTagged(PdfWriter.markAll);
        document.AddAuthor("DiY");
        document.AddSubject("DiY");
        document.AddLanguage("it-IT");
        document.AddCreationDate();
        writer.CreateXmpMetadata();
        //writer.setCompressionLevel(9);
        // step 3: we open the document
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent; // Holds the PDF data
        // step 4:
        reader = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
        PdfTemplate page;
        // Get number of pages:
        int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
        {
            document.NewPage();
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0d, 0d);
        }
    }
    catch (DocumentException de)
    {
        throw de;
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        throw ioe;
    }
    // step 5: we close the document
    document.Close();
    reader.Close();
    document.Dispose();
    reader.Dispose();
    ms.Flush();
    return ms.GetBuffer();
}
```

PS: if I try to generate a PDF/A B1, B2 or B3 it works very well, but I need to generate a level A document!

Answer (score 2):

The B stands for Basic; it means that you want to make sure that the visual representation of the document is preserved for the long term. The A stands for Accessible; it means that your document needs to contain semantic information about its content. It also means that every image that you add, needs to have a description.

Take a look at the official FAQ, more specifically to the question about creating an accessible PDF: [How can I generate a PDF/UA compatible PDF with iText?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-generate-pdfua-compatible-pdf-itext)

We add an `Alt` description to an Image `Chunk` in this example:

```
Image i = Image.getInstance(FOX);
CHunk c = new Chunk(i, 0, -24);
c.setAccessibleAttribute(PdfName.ALT, new PdfString("Fox"));
```

You are creating your document in a very awkward way. You import pages that might not be accessible into a document that should be accessible. That is **never going to work!!!**

If the original PDF is tagged, you are throwing away all the pre-existing semantic information by copying pages without copying the structure tree. If your problem is that you need to add Alt Text for images, you should read this question: [Add alternative text for an image in tagged pdf (PDF/UA) using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036200/add-alternative-text-for-an-image-in-tagged-pdf-pdf-ua-using-itext)

If the original PDF isn't tagged, you are going to cheat on your customer, because you just copy the content page by page without caring about the semantics of the content. If the original document contains a table, you should create a structure tree root and mark that table as such. That is very difficult, if not impossible. You may need a human to detect the semantic structure of the document, and that human may need to tag the PDF manually.

Imagine a PDF that isn't accessible, and that contains a picture of a fox and a dog. In that case, you would need to add an alternative description of that image, for instance saying "A quick brown fox jumping over a lazy dog."

How is a machine going to do that? More specifically: how can a machine "see" that the image is an image of a fox jumping over a dog.

**Summarized:** No matter how many times you post this question (see also [Add alternative text for an image in Tagged PDF in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938326/add-alternative-text-for-an-image-in-tagged-pdf-in-c-sharp) and probably some other questions you already deleted), **your question is wrong!** You can not simply take a PDF that is not accessible, and pour it into a PDF that is accessible without providing the proper tags. Providing the proper tags is something that requires human intelligence; a machine can't do it without human help.

Your persistence indicates that you want a solution that validates a PDF as PDF/A level A *on a technical level* and that you don't care if the PDF validates *on a human level*. Please be aware that you can be sued if you do that. In Canada, the fines can be as high as 100,000 Canadian dollars. Pleading ignorance won't help you, since you've had a PDF expert explain that your assumptions about converting PDFs to accessible PDFs are wrong.

Comment: Thank's very much Bruno! Is for a university project!